# I interrupted method when it sleep() and don't get an exception

Tags: java, multithreading

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html) says that `sleep()` throws `InterruptedException` when another thread interrupts this thread while sleep is active. So why I have an infinity loop there but don't `InterruptedException`?

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Test2 t2 = new Test2();
        t2.start();
        t2.sleep(1_000);
        t2.interrupt();
        
       
    }
}

class Test2 extends Thread
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
       while (true) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(At least) four problems:

---

Firstly, you're not actually making `t2` sleep. `Thread.sleep` is a static method, so `t2.sleep(1_000)` is actually effectively `Thread.sleep(1_000)`, so you're just making [the current thread sleep](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-).

(Can you imagine the mayhem you could cause if you were allowed to make other threads sleep arbitrarily...?)

---

Secondly, you're not actually checking for interruption in `Test2`. So, when you do interrupt it, nothing is listening for the interruption, so nothing will happen.

If you want to check for interruption, you could do something like

```
 while (!interrupted()) {}
```

but even this won't throw an `InterruptedException`: the loop will just stop executing.

---

Thirdly, `Test2` did throw an `InterruptedException` in its `run()` method, it would have to be handled within that method. `InterruptedException` is a checked exception, so you can't add `throws InterruptedException` to its signature, because `run()` doesn't declare that it throws any checked exceptions. As such, it would never "escape" the method.

---

Fourthly, even if you did manage to get the `InterruptedException` to escape the `Thread.run()` method (there are devious and vile ways to do this), that doesn't mean it would be catchable inside the main thread. The exception would be handled by the uncaught exception handler, and the main thread would continue none-the-wiser.

Comment: I don't wanted the loop to break I wanted to cause ```InterruptedException``` in ```t2``` thread, but I don't knew that t2.sleep() = Thread.sleep()

Comment: @Denis_newbie even if you don't want the loop to break, you have to actually check for interruption to know if you've been interrupted.